# How to make use of connection pool across various Python Scripts which are designed to execute SQL's on database

Tags: python-3.x, database, connection-pooling

Currently within Python script I am creating a database connection and executing the SQL...

But in my scenario, this approach taking more time on the connection creation compared to SQL execution..

So the solution I am looking at is to create a connection pool object and make use of it across the Python scripts which are designed to execute SQL's on database.

Anyone have any idea/experience of creating connection pool object in Python and made use it in various user database scripts? If you so could you please let me know how it is being implemented?

I Tried This:

Creating connection pool object:

```
import sqlalchemy.pool as pool
import jaydebeapi
import datetime


if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(<<host>>:<<port>>",
                              {'user': "user-id",
                               'password': "pw"
                               },
                              "<<jdbc>>.jar")

    mypool = pool.QueuePool(conn, max_overflow=10, pool_size=5, reset_on_return=False)

    while True:
        continue
```

Now I tried of accessing this object in another script where I need to execute SQL's:

```
from dc_connection_pool import mypool
```

and getting into

NameError: name 'mypool' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are executing mypool inside a if statement that only runs when it is called directly. This statement will not initialize when you try to execute this statement from a different script.

Please refer to below link:
[https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)